# Image Magick - trim and repage - loss of quality

Tags: imagemagick, resolution, trim, loss

When I use this command to trim a PDF file:

`convert -fuzz 1% -trim +repage multi0.pdf multi0new.pdf`

The result is very disappointing and the trimmed image size becomes more than 10 times lower than the source.

Is there any way to make a clean image trimming without loss of quality?

(here it is, before and after)

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have to use the [`-density`](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#density) option with a higher value than the default of 72 dpi. Try 300 for a start:

```
convert -density 300 -fuzz 1% -trim +repage multi0.pdf multi0new.pdf
```

Note that higher density values will increase the output file size.